# Next JS publicRuntimeConfig not being set at runtime

Tags: next.js

I have a next.config.js file with the following:

```
module.exports = {
serverRuntimeConfig: {},
publicRuntimeConfig: {
    cmsBase: process.env.CMS_BASE || 'defaultValue',
},
};
```

and I have two npm scripts, for build and run that look like this:

```
"build": "cross-env CMS_BASE=build next build",
"start": "cross-env-shell CMS_BASE=start next start"
```

I'm reading the values back like this in my app:

```
const {publicRuntimeConfig} = getConfig();
const cmsBase = publicRuntimeConfig.cmsBase;
```

but the value of cmsBase is always 'build'. I can't get this var to be set at runtime at all.  If I remove the CMS_BASE=build from the build script, then the value comes out as 'defaultValue' from the next.config.js file. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

So in case anyone else has this problem, it seems that passing a default value inside publicRuntimeConfig overrides whatever you set at runtime, as does the one you set at build time.

So if you want a runtime var to work, don't create a default in the definition, do it in the app later. And don't use a build-time var with the same name.